# How to set calendar alarm in tizen

Tags: tizen

I am able to set an event in my calender. My code is

```
var ev = new tizen.CalendarEvent
    ({
        description : document.getElementById('des').value,
        summary : document.getElementById('summ').value,
        startDate : new tizen.TZDate(yy, mm, dd, h, m),
        duration : new tizen.TimeDuration(dur1, "HOURS"),
        location : document.getElementById('loc').value,
    });
```

How could I set a calendarAlarm event to this? i.e. I want to enable the alarm to the event. Please give code if anyone knows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got the answer

```
calendar = tizen.calendar.getDefaultCalendar("EVENT");
var ev = new tizen.CalendarEvent({
description : document.getElementById('description1').value,
summary : document.getElementById('Summary1').value,
startDate : new tizen.TZDate(yy, mm, dd, h, m),
duration : new tizen.TimeDuration(dur1, "HOURS"),
location : document.getElementById('Location1').value,
var alarm = new tizen.CalendarAlarm(new tizen.TimeDuration(1, "MINS"), "SOUND");
ev.alarms = [alarm]; 
calendar.add(ev);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code I tested on the [Tizen phone](https://www.tizen.org/blogs/bdub/2012/tizen-developer-hardware-now-available) and it works:

```
    var mycalendar;
    try{        
        mycalendar = tizen.calendar.getDefaultCalendar("EVENT");
        var calendarItem = new tizen.CalendarEvent();

        calendarItem.description = "Description";
        calendarItem.summary = "Summary";
        calendarItem.location = "StackOverflow";
        calendarItem.startDate = new tizen.TZDate(2012, 8, 7, hour, minute);
        calendarItem.duration = new tizen.TimeDuration(duration, "MINS");

        mycalendar.add(calendarItem);

    }
    catch(add_exception){
        alert("Exceptie adauga : " + add_exception.message);
    }
```

In your answer the code has errors you didn't closed `CalendarEvent({`'s bracket and parenthesis and there is a comma standing stray at the end of `location` line.